# alignment of text in rows when using lists with tabular

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, lists, enumerate, itemize

i want to place list items in a table but the text inside a row isn't aligned properly.

The first table shows the "hard coded" solution i want (although i dont necessarily need the items inside the rules, but it also would be good to know how to achieve this).

The other tables show the output with the tabular inside the enumerate environtment. The third table additionally has the `nosep` option of the `enumitem` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.33\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{*{4}{p{0.5cm}}}\toprule
        1. & a & b & c\\\midrule
        2. & a & b & c\\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.33\textwidth}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \begin{tabular}{*{3}{p{0.5cm}}}\toprule
            \item a & b & c\\\midrule
            \item a & b & c\\\bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.33\textwidth}
    \begin{enumerate}[nosep]
        \begin{tabular}{*{3}{p{0.5cm}}}\toprule
            \item a & b & c\\\midrule
            \item a & b & c\\\bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: did you try the `listliketab` package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution, based on `listliketab`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{listliketab}%
\newcounter{tabenum}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\addtocounter{tabenum}{1}\thetabenum.}

\begin{document}

\begin{listliketab}
\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{0.3em}}l*{3}{p{0.5cm}}}%
        \toprule
        \tabitem & a & b & c\\%
        \midrule
        \tabitem & a & b & c\\%
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{listliketab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: After @Thruston's suggestion i was almost at this solution, but i couldnt deal with the vertical spacing. Also if one wants to use it in a Subenumeration (nested) it seems like u have to manually change the style by `\renewcommand{\thetabenum}{\alph{tabenum}}`. Thx for the answer

Comment: @J. Doe: Yes, it has nothing automatic. You'll note I didn't really use the machinery of `listliketab` as it didn't produce a correct spacing.